# Pass spring message with additional content to macro

Tags: spring, freemarker

I have written a macro that prints HTML output with passed value. Let's say:

```
<@myMacro 'foo'>
```

Right now I'd like to pass to this macro a message from `.properties` file.

```
<@spring.message code="key"/> // contains 'foo'
```

What I need is to pass value of `key` message with additional string like:

```
<@spring.message code="key"/>bar  // foobar
```

How can I do this to pass `foobar` to `myMacro` ?

Spring version: 2.5

Comment: Callable stuff in FM is either directive-like (`<@...>`) or method-like (`f(...)`). Method-like stuff can be used as an expression, while directive-like can't be as it prints directly to the output (unaffected by `#escape`). So, you should check if Spring provides the same functionality as a method/function too, and then you can use it as a parameter. But then be careful with HTML-escaping. As last resort, you can use the directive but capture its output, as it was shown in an answer here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution was quite simple:

```
<#assign fooVar><@spring.message code="key"/>bar</#assign>
<@myMacro fooVar>
```

Comment: Do I have to assign a new variable for each property I want to use?